# Split a string with arbitrary number of commas and spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that I'm trying to turn into a list but I get empty entries.

```
",A,B,C,D, ,,,"
returns
[, A, B, C, D,  , , ,]
```

I want to remove all "empty" commas:

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

I'm trying

```
current.split(",+\\s?")
```

which does not produce the result I want. What regex should I use instead?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Bergi its java. should that matter? I'm asking for help just with the regex.

Comment: Yes, because different languages use different regex flavours with differing capabilities and syntaxes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need two steps, but only one line:

```
String[] values = input.replaceAll("^[,\\s]+", "").split("[,\\s]+");
```

The call to `replaceAll()` removes leading separators.
The split is done on any number of separators.

The behaviour of `split()` means that a trailing blank value is ignored, so no need to trim trailing separators before splitting.

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = ",A,B,C,D, ,,,";
    String[] values = input.replaceAll("^[,\\s]+", "").split("[,\\s]+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Output:

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not only want to include the next few whitespaces into your match, but also the consecutive commata to split on them as one unit:

```
(,\s*)+
```

```
current.split("(?:,\\s*)+")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Splitter in Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) for this:

```
Splitter.on(',').omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().split(",A,B,C,D, ,,,");
```

as I find this easier to read than the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Matching any chars **other** than commas and spaces is likely to be a cleaner solution:

`/[^, ]+/g`

```
",A,B,C,D, ,,,".match(/[^, ]+/g)
// → ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

If you're working in Javascript you could also use the Lodash `_.words` method (kudos to them for the above regex):

https://lodash.com/docs#words

```
_.words('fred, barney, & pebbles', /[^, ]+/g);
// → ['fred', 'barney', '&', 'pebbles']
```