# Java Regex to get only words

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string that contains a paragraph, and I am trying to get only words in the paragraph. 
How do I get each words in paragraph excluding spaces, commas, and period?

Comment: This is what I got so far:
String[] splitStr = inputLine.split("\\s+");
I am not sure how I can exclude commas, and period in the same split.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] values = input.replaceAll("^[.,\\s]+", "").split("[.,\\s]+");
```

Original Source: [Split a string with arbitrary number of commas and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280994/split-a-string-with-arbitrary-number-of-commas-and-spaces)

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! :)

Comment: You can vote up if you are satisfied :)

Comment: @AmitK my bad, thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
str.split("\\W");
```

This will return an array of strings containing just words.

**Note:-** This can have few `""` as array elements in few cases e.g. when a comma is followed by a space.